# How to load Addons on Blender older versions

Tags: add-on

Hello Blender communitie! So i recently updated to 3.0 but i was using the fast carve addon on 2.8. Since it doesn't work on 3.0 I decided to download an older version and work from that folder whenever I need to use the addon, but for some reason in the 2.8 version, the addon is already there, and it gives me the same out of date message, "upgrade to 2.8x required". This gives me the idea that this version's addon folder is connected to the original 3.0. Is there any way that I can change this?

[image]

Expanded version:

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Tiago Baptista.

Comment: Expand the add-on's panel to review add-on version

Comment: I updated the post with the expanded version

Comment: Isn't there supposed to be two separate blender folders for each of the versions? 

Like My Computer -> Program Files -> Blender Foundation -> Blender 2.8 and Blender 3.0

That's how it looks whenever I install a new version.

Comment: What i find very strange is that when i download an older version, i get a ziped folder and to open the program e dont need to instal anything.